# select data from table 1 and get cross reference values of table 2 when table1 column name is matching with row values of column1 in table2

Tags: sql, oracle11g

Table 1

```
id |    check | status 
1  |    abc   | 1        
2  |    def   | 3
```

Table 2

```
Column1 |     rawvalue | to_be_updated_value|   
check   |     abc      | new    
status  |     3        | 3333
```

Please help me to write select statement to get the following output in Oracle11g

Expected Output:

```
id |    check     | status     
1  |    **new**   | 1             
2  |    def       | **3333**
```

Comment: Please explain what you want to achieve. You described the data but what output do you want? What have you tried? (And rename question to describe what doesn't work and not what's your question)

Comment: Also, please tag the RDBMS you are working with.

Comment: Hi I want the 'to_be_updated_value' data in place of original data when the column name of table1 matches with column1 of table 2 and corresponding value of that column should match with rawvalue

Comment: In simpler words I want select statement which should lookup on table2 for the updated data in place of original data.. 
(Im new to sql , im using Toad)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the first thing I think you want to do (applies to SQL Server):

```
SELECT ISC.COLUMN_NAME, T2.*
FROM <YourDatabase>.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS ISC
INNER JOIN Table2 T2 
ON T2.Column1 = ISC.COLUMN_NAME
WHERE ISC.TABLE_NAME = N'Table1';
```